# Not to use nested_form gem for a specific form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nested-forms

I'm facing an issue with nested_form gem. I have implemented nested_form gem in my project. But for one specific form, I don't want to use the nested_form gem. For more clarity about the issue, below is the code....

```
= f.simple_fields_for :product do |prod|
  = prod.input :name
  = prod.input :description
  .controls
    = prod.link_to_remove 'Remove Product', class: 'btn btn-danger btn-small'
  hr
= f.link_to_add 'Add Product', :product, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-small'
```

The above one is the typical way to implement the nested forms. But in the below form, I don't want the link_to_add. Instead, I would like the nested form to display directly... For example:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :comment do |eve|
  = eve.input :commentable_type
  = eve.input :commentable_id
```

In the above form, the nested fields are not being displayed(because i'm not using the link_to_add). So, how do i override the features of nested_form gem. By the way, I'm using slim template.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build comment strict in the form-view, before your simple_fields for comment, like this:

`- resource.comments.build if resource.comments.blank?` (if your relation is has_many)

OR

`- resource.build_comment if resource.comment.blank?` (if relation is has_one)